# Using form data and generating HTML based on it

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, web-applications

Looking for something to take data from a form like this one:

```
<form id="rendered-form" name="rendered-form">
  <div class="rendered-form">
    <div class="fb-text form-group field-text-1534368808722">
      <label class="fb-text-label" for="text-1534368808722">Name</label><input class="form-control" id="text-1534368808722" name="text-1534368808722" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="fb-text form-group field-text-1534368811041">
      <label class="fb-text-label" for="text-1534368811041">Email</label><input class="form-control" id="text-1534368811041" name="text-1534368811041" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="fb-text form-group field-text-1534368811041">
      <label class="fb-text-label" for="text-1534368811041">Link</label><input class="form-control" id="text-1534368811041" name="text-1534368811042" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

And insert the data into a HTML template. For example:

```
<div class="name">FORM TEXT HERE</div>
<div class="email">FORM TEXT HERE</div>
<a href="FORM TEXT HERE">link</a>
```

I would love to use Vue.js for this if at all possible, I've been playing around with it and this seems like something it would be capable of.

I'm trying to use this to quickly make AMP pages (I know I could do it programmatically, but due to restrictions I cannot at this time). I don't want to have a database, it doesn't need to store this. I just want to be able to insert my data, press a button, and have it spit out HTML or an HTML file based on the template and provided data and be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already handled the form submit, you can change the content of your divs with js selectors, like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("name")[0].innerHTML = nameFromFormInput;
```

Comment: Wow, that simple. Let me try this out. I was seriously overthinking this.

Comment: If you're using vue, you can add models (v-models) to the inputs and do the binding inside the divs

<input v-model="variable" class="form-control" id="input_id" name="input_name" type="text">

<div class="name">{{variable}}</div>

If you use this, it will output in real time.

Hope it helps you!!